# Expected value of Loss/objective Function

Tags: probability, statistics

I am trying to get the expected value of the objective function:
$$O(m) = 1-e^{-am}$$
with the most probable distribution being: $$f(m)=be^{-bm}$$

To the best of my understanding what I have to do is evaluate this integral:
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}{(1-e^{-am})(be^{-bm})dm}$$ for which I get the result $$\frac{a}{a+b}$$
Is this correct? Because I am a little confused with the terminology in the wikipedia.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If it is of any use here is the wikipedia link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your result for the value of the integral is correct. If you know moment generating functions then a quick check is to recognize the integral as the expected value
$$\mathbb{E}(O(M))=1-\mathbb{E}(e^{-a M})=1-g_M(-a),$$ where $M$ is an exponential RV with rate $b$, $O(m)$ is as you defined, and $g_M(t)=\mathbb{E}(e^{tM})$ is the MGF of $M$. Since $g_M(t)=b/(b-t)$, for $t<b$ the result follows immediately.